# Skipped batch replay of 20ca1130-b5f7-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f

Tags: cassandra

I am seeing this in the cassandra log from time to time. Initially I thought this might have been a transaction in the commitlog for a column family that I dropped. But after stopping cassandra, clearing the commitlog directory and restarting it, the problem persists. I am using that cassandra to run stress tests, populating it with data, could that be the issue?

```
INFO 18:18:07,356 Compacted 2 sstables to [/mnt/data/cassandra/data/system/batchlog/system-batchlog-jb-18839,].  32,564,368 bytes to 30,618,578 (~94% of original) in 3,860ms = 7.564806MB/s.  174,325 total partitions merged to 174,325.  Partition merge counts were {1:174325, }
WARN 18:19:08,491 Skipped batch replay of 20ca1130-b5f7-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:11,012 Skipped batch replay of bf8b9350-b5f4-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:13,996 Skipped batch replay of 7fba4b90-b5f4-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:14,556 Skipped batch replay of d5a94770-b5f6-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:16,647 Skipped batch replay of 9caed560-b5f7-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:16,935 Skipped batch replay of 60d8a580-b5f6-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:18,195 Skipped batch replay of ee991940-b5f6-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:19,448 Skipped batch replay of e59052f0-b5f6-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
WARN 18:19:24,064 Skipped batch replay of 11b8cc41-b5f7-11e3-af2a-3d383ca57c8e due to org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=b37f38a2-2bcd-3d30-9f5a-9f0de4cb02db
INFO 18:19:24,610 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-batchlog@1826954056(0/2097152 serialized/live bytes, 174325 ops)
INFO 18:19:24,620 Writing Memtable-batchlog@1826954056(0/2097152 serialized/live bytes, 174325 ops)
```

Comment: What is the version of cassandra you are using. I see a problem posted in jira and they have updated a patch for the same. Did you start getting that after dropping a column family https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6822

Comment: 2.0.6, so it should be ok in that version

Comment: I am pretty sure this occurs after dropping a keyspace while there are transaction log files. It seems it tries to play those log files and I get a ton of messages.

Comment: oops, actually it is caused by batches. I stopped cassandra, cleaned up the commitlog directory, restarted cassandra and the issue still occurs. So seems it can't flush batches when the keyspace was dropped.

Comment: tried 2.0.7, the problem still not sorted out